# Verb for "to be a cornerstone"

Tags: single-word-requests

> The central idea ____ the observed structure

If central idea didn't exist or was taken out of the equation, the observed structure would no longer be observed.

I would like to use cornerstones, mainstays, etc. as verbs, but preferably an established word that has the same meaning: the subject is foundational to the object.

"support" doesn't work well enough because I also want to connote the idea that as soon as you remove the subject, the object totally falls apart, Jenga tower or house-of-cards style. Remove a table leg and watch the table fall over. Support doesn't imply absolute necessity.

I would prefer a single word to a compound word like props-up, and something with more gravitas: cornerstone, mainstay, keystone, foundation, sound so powerful, huge, and significant. But "props-up" sounds like a ramshackle job.

Comment: Is it the idea that *binds* your structure together?

Comment: @YosefBaskin no, it's just one of the table legs, or one of the cards, or one of the jenga bricks. Not the glue.

Comment: For a verb that can be used as a noun, try _anchor_.

Comment: Try Variety.com, the online version of Variety. Hollywood has so many kingpins (and kingpin wannabes paying for ad space) that Variety writers had to get quite creative with their wording. It’s tamer than it used to be, but still a rich source of words and expressions.

Answer (score 5):

The word **underpin** is primarily used to mean supporting a building from underneath, but can also apply to organisational structures. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/underpin) has

> **underpin**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Support (a building or other structure) from below by laying a solid foundation below ground level or by substituting stronger for weaker materials.
> *At present, it is not thought that underpinning the foundations would be enough to save the building*
>
> **2** Support, justify, or form the basis for.
> *The idea of fairness that underpins the democratic process is grounded in different ways in different theories.*

So the sentence could be

> The central idea underpinned the observed structure.

This conveys that the 'central idea' is essential for the 'observed structure' to exist, and the association with buildings and foundations gives it solidity.

Comment: Similarly *undergird*

Answer (score 2):

> The central idea **upholds** the observed structure.

**uphold** (v.)

> To support or sustain physically; to keep from falling or sinking.
>
> To support, sustain, maintain, by aid or assistance; to preserve unimpaired or intact. OED

---

> Racial discrimination denies equality and thus undermines the
> structure which that **cornerstone upholds**. [US Commission on Civil
> Rights; *Housing in Washington*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Housing_in_Washington/RxrRAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cornerstone%20upholds&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover)

> In a building the base **upholds** the pillars, and the pillars uphold
> the entire structure; this is what the church is to God. [*The
> Collected Works of Witness Lee*, Vol. 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Collected_Works_of_Witness_Lee_1956/jCjHDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=upholds%20the%20entire%20structure&pg=PT38&printsec=frontcover)

> To take this road, every member of the Jewish People must have a sense
> of historic destiny continuing through him; he must feel that he is
> the last remaining pillar which **upholds** the entire structure of
> Judaism. [Irvin Bunim; *Ethics from Sinai*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethics_from_Sinai/_s8SzHm3yJsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=upholds%20the%20entire%20structure&pg=PA285&printsec=frontcover)

> Kapha has its main function in the structure, cohesion, and lubrication of the body. Kapha holds together the tissues, jonts, neck, chest, and head, to
> name a few. By and large, kapha **upholds** the entire body and gives
> you the structure and foundation you have. [Varsha Khatri; *Think
> Healthy, Choose Healthy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Think_Healthy_Choose_Healthy/kNQqEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=upholds%20the%20entire%20structure&pg=PT42&printsec=frontcover).

> The dam consists of the entire structure which **upholds** the pond,
> and extends to and includes the first lock. [Wisconsin Supreme Court;
> *Wisconsin Reports*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wisconsin_Reports/8MFbAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=upholds%20the%20entire%20structure&pg=PA396&printsec=frontcover)